# Escaping special characters in command prompt

Tags: cmd, escaping

I'm trying to run this line of code in cmd:

```
wscript.exe hidden.vbs "test.bat http://www.googlec.com/index.php?act=viewprofile&id=1"
```

but because of the special characters `"&"` and `"="`, this is what really happens:

```
wscript.exe hidden.vbs "test.bat http://www.googlec.com/index.php?act"
```

I've already tried to escape them with `^` but it didn't work.

How do I properly escape these characters?

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\User>echo "test.bat http://www.googlec.com/index.php?act=viewprofile&id=1"
"test.bat http://www.googlec.com/index.php?act=viewprofile&id=1"
```

Then using this code

```
WScript.Echo WScript.Arguments(0)
WScript.Echo WScript.Arguments(1)
```

We get

```
C:\Users\User>cscript //nologo "C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop\Bat and vbs\CMDLineArgs.vbs" "test.bat http://www.go
oglec.com/index.php?act=viewprofile&id=1"
test.bat http://www.googlec.com/index.php?act=viewprofile&id=1
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Bat and vbs\CMDLineArgs.vbs(2, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Subscript out of range
```

Showing it is read correctly.

Comment: I'm showing you there is no problem as you describe

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the args in a variable first

```
set vbarg = "test.bat http://www.googlec.com/index.php?act=viewprofile&id=1"
wscript.exe hidden.vbs %vbarg%
```